# Operation is not allowed when object is closed VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel, stored-procedures

My code fails with the above error when it reaches the 4th line of the following code. I've used this same format earlier in my program and it works just fine. If more code is needed to resolve the error I'd be happy to post. Thanks.

```
With rsTIP19
.ActiveConnection = cnTIP
.Open "exec usp_Service_Data_Query_QA"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Service_Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rsTIP19
.Close
End With
```

Comment: Is your stored procedure definitely returning a resultset?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes it works perfectly in sql

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of **exec**? You should test to for `.BOF` or `.EOF`.

```
With rsTIP19

    .ActiveConnection = cnTIP
    .Open "usp_Service_Data_Query_QA"
    If Not .BOF or .EOF then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Service_Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rsTIP19
    End If

    .Close

End With
```

Comment: I get the same error as before when trying that code.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would get that error on line 4.  I would think that the code should break on `.Open` ; if the connection was closed.